# Method or Data member not found User Form

Tags: excel, vba, offset, userform, commandbutton

[Command Button Shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn5jx.png) I have created this Command Button Shapes For User Form which looks like.
[User Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOigo.png)
It has different codes for borders.
When I click UserForm Command Button. It throws me this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjlM.png)

Can Someone tell where I am wrong?

First Edit:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
    Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2).Select
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2)")
    rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    UserForm2.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure Just wait for a sec.

Comment: Added the code Tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2)")` - I don't think the Range member takes that string as a valid argument (The string is a VBA statement, not a range value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out Shape Command Button Code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2).Select
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

And UserForm Code

```
ActiveCell.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    UserForm2.Hide
```